# Lumen make:command

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm trying to execute code within my Lumen install via the command line. In full Laravel , I've read that you can use commands to achieve this via "make:command", but Lumen does not seem to support this command.

Is there anyway to enable this command? Failing that, what's the best way of running code from the CLI in Lumen?

Thanks

Comment: Lumen does not have builtin Commands support

Comment: There is a package `flipbox\lumen-generator` however I am having hard time registering this package inside `bootstrap\app.php`. Probably it's because not compatible with `lumen:5.7.*`

Comment: checkout the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716203/laravel-lumen-framework5-7-and-flipbox-lumen-generator5-6-class-not-fou/52717071#52717071

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the `artisan` CLI in Lumen as the same way as in Laravel but with fewer built-in commands. To see all built-in commands, use the `php artisan` command in Lumen.

Although there is no `make:command` command at Lumen, you can create your custom command:

- Add new command class inside the `app/Console/Commands` folder, you can use the sample class template of the framework [`serve` command](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.0/src/Console/Commands/ServeCommand.php)
- Register your custom command by adding your created class to the `$commands` member inside the `app/Console/Kernel.php` file.

Except the command generating, you can use the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/commands) for commands when working with Lumen.

Comment: what about using flipbox\lumen-generator:"^5.6" package?

Comment: Hieu Le I used `flipbox\lumen-generator` checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716203/laravel-lumen-framework5-7-and-flipbox-lumen-generator5-6-class-not-fou/52717071#52717071

Comment: Hi @xiarnousx, thank you for the package you suggested. My answer was posted three years ago :)

Answer (score 19):

Here is a template for a new command.
You can just copy and paste this in to a new file and start working.
I tested it on lumen 5.7.0

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class CommandName extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'commandSignature';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        $this->info('hello world.');
    }
}
```

Then register it on the Kernel.php file.

```
/**
* The Artisan commands provided by your application.
*
* @var array
*/
protected $commands = [
   \App\Console\Commands\CommandName::class
];
```

Comment: It says: ReflectionException Class App\Console\Commands\CommandName does not exits in ...Container.php:752

Comment: @user1633272 - you'll see that error, if you haven't correctly specified your class in `app/Console/Kernel.php`. I've just submitted an edit to the answer to use the better practice `::class` nottion, which most IDE's will highlight to you if the class doesn't exist (they won't if it's a string).

Answer (score 11):

When you create your command class use this:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
```

Instead of what was described above about using `serve command` example

Comment: Please write the solution, links can break.

Comment: As predicted, broken link

Comment: I removed the broken link and kept the solution