# laravel/lumen-framework:"5.7.*" and flipbox/lumen-generator:"^5.6" Class Not Found

Tags: lumen

I think this is related to composer autoload not detecting packages outside laravel/lumen-framework/src

Is my above assumption to the below problem correct? Shall I include psr-4 key inside `"autoload-dev"` nested object?

I really appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Below is Error Exception, `composer.json` snippet and Stack Trace Logs

[image: Exception]

Below composer.json

```
        {
        ...
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "database/seeds",
                "database/factories"
            ],
            "psr-4": {
                "App\\": "app/"
            }
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
            "classmap": [
                "tests/"
            ]
        },
        ...
    }
```

Below is the stack trace log found under `storage/lumen.log`

```
[2018-10-09 07:51:53] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: 
Class '\FlipBox\LumenGenerator\LumenGeneratorServiceProvider' not found in 
/var/www/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php:183
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/bootstrap/app.php(86): Laravel\Lumen\Application->register('\\FlipBox\\LumenG...')
#1 /var/www/public/index.php(14): require('/var/www/bootst...')
#2 {main} {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): 
Class '\\FlipBox\\LumenGenerator\\LumenGeneratorServiceProvider' not 
found at /var/www/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php:183)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/bootstrap/app.php(86): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->register('\\\\FlipBox\\\\LumenG...')
#1 /var/www/public/index.php(14): require('/var/www/bootst...')
#2 {main}
"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was really a stupid mistake, after debugging and going to the north pole back and forth. I figured out that I had the class namespace referenced wrongly so instead of using below:

```
if ($app->environment() !== 'production') {
    $app->register(FlipBox\LumenGenerator\LumenGeneratorServiceProvider::class);
}
```

I should have used small letter `b` instead of `B` so the below works:

```
if ($app->environment() !== 'production') {
    $app->register(Flipbox\LumenGenerator\LumenGeneratorServiceProvider::class);
}
```

Then doing `php artisan list` you will get all the `make:*` goodies:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What really worked for me, was to run `composer install` or `composer update`, that installed dependencies that I had not yet installed (due to changes made by others by the use of GIT repository).